# Copy folder contents to current working directory

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to copy the contents of a network folder to the local working directory of a script. Ideally something like this:

```
<copy_app.exe> \\Destination\Folder $CurrentDirectory
```

... except that I don't know what `$CurrentDirectory` is as it's part of a deployment workflow and could be on any machine in a guid-generated folder.

Ideally, I'd like a switch to change the folder/file attributes like robocopy does (`/a+:n`) because the files I'm getting are going to be read-only and I need them to be normal.

Comment: What are you scripting in? Are you asking the method for a certain scripting languauge?

Comment: @PlanetCaravan: Whichever scripting environment makes sense. batch or powershell are preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>.</kbd> to refer to the current folder